# Emacs function keys insert text instead of functionig as a shortkey

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

Since the last emacs update (`GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8`) my function keys stopped working.

I always used F10 to open menu and F8 to open neotree pane.
Right now pressing F10 inserts `[21~` while F8 inserts `[19~` to current buffer.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and terminal with all disabled keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Besides Emacs upgrade, nothing changed on your Ubuntu?

Comment: @ringø Nope. Not at all. I mean. I've just run regular ubuntu update, but I don't think any of the updated programs could affect it.

Comment: A wild guess is that Emacs isn't the problem, and your terminal changed. Mostly likely you are running `gnome-terminal`. Do you have the same problem with `xfce4-terminal`? You can install it with `apt-get install xfce4-terminal`. If that doesn't work, try running `C-h k <f10>` in Emacs and tell us what you see.

Comment: @BrianMalehorn same behavior in xfce4

Comment: What does `C-h k <f10>` say? Alternatively, you could run Emacs in its own window instead of inside a terminal. I believe you can accomplish this by just running `emacs` from a terminal.

Comment: `C-h k <f10>` runs help for `M-[` and writes `21~` to the buffer.
In GUI emacs it works as intended but I'd really rather not rely on the GUI version. Especially that I always run my emacs in TMUX session